# Need some help with onClick and an if/else issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, if-statement

I have a menu with seven items. If you click the first item, div one shows. If you click any other item (2 through 7) div two shows. That's what I'm looking to do.

I'm new at all this but am pretty sure it's an if/else function, such that if I click on `<a id="1">`, show the first div, else show the second div. I suppose I can do a hide/show to get back to the first div.

I'm going to keep poking around, but if I can't find it, any help is surely appreciated.

```
<div id="one">
Div contents (has a jquery slider in it)
</div>
<div id="two">
Div contents (contents chosen by user from menu items, below)
</div>
<!--menu-->
<a href="#" id="first_panel"><!--has slider controlled within div-->

<a href"#" id="data_part_one">&nbsp;</a>
<a href"#" id="data_part_two">&nbsp;</a>
<a href"#" id="data_part_three">&nbsp;</a>
...
<a href"#" id="data_part_six">&nbsp;</a>
```

Where the data from menu items two through seven will appear in div two.

---

I got it to work with the code, below. If it's ugly, show me the error of my ways and I'll thank you.

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function() {
        if ($("#t0").is("")) {
        $("#open_panel").show();
        }
        else
        {
        $("#open_panel").hide();
        $("#res_panel").show();
        }
    });

    $('#t0').click(function() {
        $('#open_panel').show();
        $('#res_panel').hide();
    });
```

Comment: What programming language/environment ?

Comment: @Paul it's tagged as JavaScript.

Comment: I think you'll get more useful answers if you post a fragment of your HTML (e.g., the menu and the divs).

Comment: @Jacob - it's tagged as JavaScript *now*, but the question had no useful/appropriate tags and very little detail or context when I posted my comment.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to over-explain myself. Simply, If I click on the first menu item, show div one. If I click on any other menu item, show div two.

Comment: As it would just so happen I lost my I-net connection while typing a response. Don't know when you'll get this one, but yes, I did try what you proposed with no luck. I'll post what I added by editing the original post if you're able to respond to this comment.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$( 'a' ).not( '#link_id1' ).click( function( e ) {
   $( '#div_2' ).show();
   e.preventDefault();
}).end().filter( '#link_id1' ).click( function( e ) {
   $( '#div_1' ).show();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or:

```
$( 'a' ).click( function( e ) {
   if( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) == 'link_id1' ) {
       $( '#div_1' ).show();
   } else {
       $( '#div_2' ).show();
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to cancel the event, else *both* handlers will get triggered when he clicks the first `li`. (Also note that he indicated he was using `a`, not `li`, but hopefully he can generalise -- since he didn't post any markup!)

Comment: Okay, I got it to work with if/else. It's probably wrong as all get out, and maybe you can take a look to see if that is the case. I'll edit original post. I'm about to post another 'issue', too.